# Probability of CDC data

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

All of this is my work, for (c) I believe its $1 - pbinom(144, 138, 2.9)$ which yields $.0192 $

For (d) I know that when D is negative, that would mean the woman is taller than the man, so I think it is just $ 69.2/63.8$ ?

Please correct me if I am wrong, Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks for showing your work. It would be best to type the question directly here, rather the posting an image (which not all users will be able to access). Also, to post only the parts for which you doubt your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use pnorm; pbinom is for binomial random variables.

```
> 1-pnorm(72,69.2,2.9)
[1] 0.1671429
```

2. Correct
3. $$P\left(Z\ge\frac{144-133}{\sqrt{16.82}}\right)=P(Z\ge2.726249)$$

```
> 1-pnorm(2.726249)
[1] 0.003202933
```

4. Correct
5. $$P\left(Z\le\frac{0-5.4}{\sqrt{16.82}}\right)=P(Z\le -1.316682)$$

```
> pnorm(-1.316682)
[1] 0.09397262
```

Comment: (+1) But check arithmetic in (3): `(144 - 133)/sqrt(16.82)` returns 2.682129

Answer (score 0):

(a) $P(X_1 > 72) = 0.1671.$  In R: I did not standardize because the CDF `pnorm` in R accepts
the actual means and standard deviations. [Irrelevant `pbinom` must be a typo--one I have sometimes made myself.]

```
1 - pnorm(72, 69.2, 2.9)
[1] 0.1671429

hdr = "Dist'n of Heights of Men"
curve(dnorm(x, 69.2, 2.9), 60, 80, lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2"); abline(v=72, col="red")
```

[image]

(b) OK

(c) $P(S > 144) = 0.0037.$

```
1 - pnorm(144, 69.2+63.8, sqrt(2*2.9^2))
[1] 0.00365776

hdr = "Dist'n of Sums of Heights of Couples"
curve(dnorm(x, 69.2+63.8, sqrt(2*2.9^2)), 120, 150, 
      lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main=hdr)
  abline(h=0, col="green2"); abline(v=144, col="red")
```

[image]

(d) OK

(e) $P(D < 0) = 0.0940.$

```
pnorm(0, 69.2-63.8, sqrt(2*2.9^2))
[1] 0.09397269


hdr = "Dist'n of Man's Ht - Woman's Ht"
curve(dnorm(x, 69.2-63.8, sqrt(2*2.9^2)), -10, 20, 
            lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2"); abline(v=0, col="red")
```

[image]

Also, by simulation of a million couples, which should give
a probability correct to about two places.

```
set.seed(2021)
m = rnorm(10^6, 69.2, 2.9)
w = rnorm(10^6, 63.8, 2.9)
mean(m < w)
[1] 0.094211
```